# C++ implicit function calls

Tags: c++

Will c++ implicit function calls be a feature of C++0x ? It is an interesting feature, but I haven't seen any progress on this and the GCC C++0x page didn't even mention it.

See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1611.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they will not be included in the next standard update to C++ (C++0x).  The idea of implicit function calls (informally: use of a niladic function name in an expression evaluates to a function call instead of decaying to its address) is interesting, and it wasn't dismissed by the committee as a bad idea.  It was classified as: "Not ready for C++0x, but open to resubmit in future." (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2869.html).

Comment: Uff, I'm just looking for a SIMPLE way to do properties ... :)

Comment: Ha ha. I was about to post the same question for the exact same reason.